# How can I import the fga_log$ table with impdp Oracle 12 R1

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, audit, impdp, expdp

I am trying to import with impdp a save made as follows:

```
expdp '"sys/mmm as sysdba"' full=y COMPRESSION=ALL DIRECTORY=LOGICS_EXPORTS COMPRESSION_ALGORITHM=BASIC LOGTIME=ALL CONTENT=ALL DUMPFILE=FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCT-2019%U.dmp LOGFILE=FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCT-2019.log PARALLEL= 7 INCLUDE=AUDIT_TRAILS
```

*The idea is to have the fga audit table saved, the export is completed successfully but now, when importing:*

```
impdp '"sys/mmm as sysdba"' DIRECTORY=LOGICS_EXPORTS PARALLEL=7 TRANSFORM=DISABLE_ARCHIVE_LOGGING:Y:TABLE DUMPFILE=FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCT-2019%U.dmp LOGFILE=IMPORT-FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCT-2019.log TABLES=SYS.FGA_LOG$FOR_EXPORT REMAP_TABLE=SYS.FGA_LOG$FOR_EXPORT:FGA_AUDITS;
```

**ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39166: Object SYS.FGA_LOG was not found or could not be exported or imported.**

*This is the log of the expdp:*

```
16-OCT-19 10:03:20.315: Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
16-OCT-19 10:03:22.251: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/EARLY_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE_DATA
16-OCT-19 10:03:22.449: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/TABLE_DATA
16-OCT-19 10:03:22.688: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE_DATA
16-OCT-19 10:03:25.579: Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 1.500 GB
16-OCT-19 10:03:25.969: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PRE_SYSTEM_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
16-OCT-19 10:03:25.971: . . exported "SYS"."DAM_CLEANUP_EVENTS$"                 5.328 KB       7 rows
16-OCT-19 10:03:25.973: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PRE_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
16-OCT-19 10:03:25.976: . . exported "SYS"."DAM_CLEANUP_JOBS$"                       0 KB       0 rows
16-OCT-19 10:03:26.015: . . exported "SYS"."DAM_CONFIG_PARAM$"                   5.148 KB      15 rows
16-OCT-19 10:03:26.353: . . exported "SYS"."KU$_USER_MAPPING_VIEW"               5.257 KB      37 rows
16-OCT-19 10:03:30.827: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/EARLY_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE
16-OCT-19 10:03:33.541: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/EARLY_POST_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
16-OCT-19 10:03:37.260: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/TABLE
16-OCT-19 10:04:02.411: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE
16-OCT-19 10:04:15.722: . . exported "SYS"."AUD$"                                172.9 MB 7354730 rows
16-OCT-19 10:04:25.963: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_POST_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOU/MARKER
16-OCT-19 10:04:25.968: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
16-OCT-19 10:04:25.982: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/FINAL_POST_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
16-OCT-19 10:04:25.986: Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/POST_SYSTEM_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
16-OCT-19 11:15:24.400: . . exported "SYS"."FGA_LOG$FOR_EXPORT"                  8.201 GB 144651189 rows
16-OCT-19 11:15:24.654: . . exported "SYS"."AUDTAB$TBS$FOR_EXPORT"               4.945 KB       2 rows
16-OCT-19 11:15:25.468: Master table "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_03" successfully loaded/unloaded
16-OCT-19 11:15:25.470: ******************************************************************************
16-OCT-19 11:15:25.471: Dump file set for SYS.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_03 is:
16-OCT-19 11:15:25.475:   /salvas/logica/buc/FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCTUBRE-201901.dmp
16-OCT-19 11:15:25.476:   /salvas/logica/buc/FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCTUBRE-201902.dmp
16-OCT-19 11:15:25.477:   /salvas/logica/buc/FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCTUBRE-201903.dmp
16-OCT-19 11:15:25.478:   /salvas/logica/buc/FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCTUBRE-201904.dmp
16-OCT-19 11:15:25.488: Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_03" successfully completed at Wed Oct 16 11:15:25 2019 elapsed 0 01:12:08
```

Comment: impdp dumpfile names not matching with dumpfiles generated by expdp, change `DUMPFILE=FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCT-2019%U.dmp ` to `DUMPFILE=FULL-INCLUDE-FGA_LOG-16-OCTUBRE-2019%U.dmp `

Comment: The problem is that I want to use the option
REMAP_TABLE
Well, I want to import into another table in another database

Comment: Are you still running into same error with IMPDP?

Comment: Yes, yes, every time I import with imdp I get an error.
It cannot be that Oracle has made this process so complex.